# What if my child has asthma?

Tags: health, asthma

I wanted to know what exactly asthma is? What are some of the triggers that could bring on the symptoms for my child?

Answer (score 2):

For your question about asthma and what triggers asthma attacks I was able to do some initial research and discovered some reliable sources that might help you learn more about this particular disease.

According to the Environmental Protection Agency http://www.epa.gov/asthma/about.html

“Asthma is a serious, sometimes life-threatening chronic respiratory disease that affects the quality of life for almost 25 million Americans, including an estimated 7 million children. Although there is no cure for asthma yet, asthma can be controlled through medical treatment and management of environmental triggers. ”

The Lung Association http://www.lung.ca/diseases-maladies/asthma-asthme/what-quoi/index_e.php describes asthma as

“a chronic (long-term) disease that makes it hard to breathe. Asthma can't be cured, but it can be managed. With proper treatment, people with asthma can lead normal, active lives.”
Triggers are also described on the Environmental Protection Agencies website as “things that can cause asthma symptoms, an episode or attack or make asthma worse. If you have asthma, you or your child could react to just one trigger or you may find that several things act as triggers.”

As described by the website http://www.noattacks.org/triggers-in-your-home
Triggers can include:
Mold, dust mites, smoke, cats, dogs, chemical irritants, air pollution, and exercise.

I found these websites by typing the phrase “internet public library” into Google. Known as Ipl2 it is one of the best free reference web sites.  Once on their homepage http://www.ipl.org/ I typed in “asthma and triggers” and reviewed the various credible websites.

I hope that these articles can help you. If you need more help, in finding other sources on asthma or irritants that can trigger asthma please feel free to respond again so that I can assist you in finding more materials. Your local doctor can also provide you with information on asthma and help discover what specifically triggers your child’s asthma.

Answer (score 0):

I had childhood asthma.  For me physical activity - lots or running etc. - triggered attacks.  But I was able to use an inhaler and be able to breath again quickly.  I just had to be careful how much running around I did in school at recess.

The upside of childhood asthma is many kids outgrow it.  By the time I was in grade 5 or 6 I had no more problems and could run all I wanted.

Asthma causes difficulty breathing.  It can feel like having a panic attack.  Modern medicine works wonders however.  I had two inhalers.  One is fast acting for when I was having an attack.  The other is used a few times a day to help prevent them.

Other things that can cause problems are alergens like dust or pets, and cold and flu (the asthma makes the repratory problems worse)

Answer (score 0):

I had childhood asthma until I was about 15 - any major exertion could bring on an attack, but with inhalers I managed to control it very well, to the point that the only times I ever had an attack were when cross-country running in sub-zero temperatures (cold air makes it a lot harder to breathe)

Mine was linked to childhood hayfever - and I just grew out of them. Still get very mild hayfever in a bad year, but no more asthma, and I ended up running marathons and doing martial arts and various extreme sports, so I wouldn't worry about asthma longer term - just be sure to get the right medicine/inhalers and see if you need to alter conditions at home (look at pets, smokers, airflow, humidity etc in the house)